# Python Tornado : Instance variable are not saved from a method to another

Tags: python, variables, reference, instance, tornado

I'm struggling for a moment with the instance variables in Tornado. My code below:

```
def initialize(self):
    self.needed_file = []

def put(self):
    try:
        if something:
            self.needed_file.append('Ninja file')
            self.needed_file.append(dico_data[0][1].decode('utf-8'))
            print(self.needed_file)
    except IndexError:
        pass   

def get(self):
    try:
        print('//' + str(self.needed_file) + '//')
    except AttributeError:
        print('{}'.format(ServerHandler.needed_file))
```

I don't manage to print the value of `self.needed_file` from `put(self)` `to get(self)`, interpreter give me this traceback.

```
['Ninja file', '/Users/corpo/DistributedBuild/]` <----------- print() from put
[I 180503 10:01:59 web:2106] 200 PUT / (::1) 11.87ms
//[]// <--------- print() from get
[E 180503 10:01:59 web:1621] Uncaught exception GET / (192.168.1.189)
```

And of course the uncaught expression is an Index Error Exception, because I'm asking get to give me a value in a list that it doesn't have.

Thanks !

Comment: For each request a new instance of a Handler is created, so `put` and `get` methods would be invoked from different instances and instance attribute `needed_file` wouldn't be shared between them.

Comment: So you mean that I have to pass these arguments as class variable ?

Comment: You don't _have to_, but you can't use instance variables for this task. There are many ways to do so: store in session, store in a DB, some app-level storage. Actually I consider storing such variables at a class-level a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Define instance variable as a part of the class

```
class Test():

    needed_file = []

    def put(self):
        print("put")
        self.needed_file.append('Ninja file')

    def get(self):
        print("get")
        print(self.needed_file)
```